# How do I use Neo4j in a reactive Spring webflux application without causing any blocking?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-webflux

I'm starting a new Spring boot project and I've chosen a neo4j graph database as there is a lot of connected data.

I would like to use Reactive Streams in the project as there is a lot of `push` notifications from the server to the client.  I'm looking at using Spring Webflux for this reason.

I'm weary of accidentally using blocking calls/api's that will negate the decision to use webflux.

I've searched for information on using neo4j with reactive streams. It doesn't look like there is a reactive driver at the moment, although there is an asynchronous mechanism using CompletableFuture.

Please could I have some guidance on how to fit these two peices, webflux & neo4j, together.

thanks

Comment: it's coming soon apparently. there was a hint on [this spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/21/this-week-in-spring-may-21-2019) and a developer working on it responded to a tweet saying there's an announcement in the coming weeks.

Answer (score -1):

Pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Noe4j entity class as the following

```
@Node
@Data
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Post {    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
}
```

Create a Repository for the Post entity

```
interface PostRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<Post, Long> 
{
}
```

Create a RestController to expose the simple CRUD RESTful APIs for the Post entity

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class PostController {    private final PostRepository posts;    @GetMapping("")
    public Flux<Post> all() {
        return this.posts.findAll();
    }    @PostMapping("")
    public Mono<Post> create(@RequestBody Post post) {
        return this.posts.save(post);
    }    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Post> get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return Mono.just(id)
                .flatMap(posts::findById)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new PostNotFoundException(id)));
    }    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Post> update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Post post) {
        return this.posts.findById(id)
                .map(p -> {
                    p.setTitle(post.getTitle());
                    p.setContent(post.getContent());                    return p;
                })
                .flatMap(this.posts::save);
    }    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Void> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return this.posts.deleteById(id);
    }}
```

Reactive programming with Neo4j check here as reference
https://hantsy.medium.com/update-accessing-neo4j-with-spring-boot-2-4-3951cb81d97d